Report viewer tools grayed out in winform application visual studio 2022NU1701
I had installed RDLC Report Designer extension. Then I installed RDLC Report Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms. But when I tried to find it, it were grayed out. I cant drag it into my form. In solution explorar there is a warning also SAYS
**Package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1652.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. **  Here is tool's and solution explorar condition(https://i.sstatic.net/eEQAS5vI.png)
I reinstalled extension and package.
Also, I deleted tools from toolbox and tried to browsing \bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll. It was undone too.
Nothing is working for me.

As the warning says:

using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework
'net8.0-windows7.0'.

You are using .net8 winform.
But RDLC targets .NET Framework WinForm.
Create  WinForms (.NET Framework) project.
